# Can I convert a CFUUID to 30 characters or less?

Tags: ios, objective-c, guid

I need to create an identifier for my iOS user that is unique. Unfortunately the database that it will be saved to has a set length of 30 characters and CFUUID's are 36 (32 if removing the dashes).

Is there a way to make it into a smaller string? I think CFUUID's are hex, so would it be possible to convert it to full ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Atwood covers this in [Equipping our ASCII Armor](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/equipping-our-ascii-armor.html). A [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk) encoded GUID results in 22 (24 including `==`) bytes. There are also other ascii formats you can use based on the post but Base64 will likely be the friendliest with the database server.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that helped.  One thing lead to another and I ended up pull the solution off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encode-on-the-iphone  Worked perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your hex string to NSData using something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/7318062/382374 (be sure to strip out the "-"s).  Then use something like http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php to convert the NSData to base64.

Comment: This is also a useful tool: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en