# Automatic mobile account creation for a Django-based iOS service

Tags: iphone, django, apple-push-notifications

I have a service with a Django-based RESTful API that is designed for iOS devices to access.  I'd like to store some user data on the server -- non-sensitive things like favorites for example.  I don't want to make a new user create an account, but I would like for the data to not be publicly available.  The service also uses Apple's Push Notification Service (APNS).  All traffic to and from the service uses TLS/SSL.

I am considering using a CFUUID generated by the device on first launch as a username and the token provided by APNS as a password.  I would create a user account after I successfully register the device with APNS and update the password if the APNS token changes.

Is this a bad idea?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: One issue in using a CFUUID as a username in Django is that User model in django.contrib.auth is 30 characters or fewer.  I believe that can be addressed by the methods suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150516/can-i-convert-a-cfuuid-to-30-characters-or-less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I've decided to take is the above but without using the APNS token as a password.  Instead, the CFUUID and token are sent as form-encoded data in the body of an HTTPS PUT request with a server-generated password to returned in the body of the response.