# QR code with location tracking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, qr-code

I am trying to create the login with QR code. I did Google and got to know How to implement QR code in Swift.
My Doubt or Question is: How do you store your QR code metadata or key or value of particular QR code? Where shall I save ?
I have 10 different QR code Images. If QR code "A" matches to key value  "A" then only View must Segue to next page.

Thank you.

Comment: may be you can use `base64 encode` , save the encoded value to database and use it when neccessary .

Comment: @Vikrant : As I am building Sample App, So I don't use database here. I have to hard code all the data. Can you give me example for base 64 encode ? and how to call it in my QRcode program?

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encoding-on-the-iphone....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to save the string values of QR code. You can easily save them in UserDefault:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(firstQRValue, forKey: "value1")
```

When you scan a QRCode, match its value with those saved in your UserDefaults.