# String request using NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, base64

I have to send `base64` string request to server .

**Code:**

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[\"Login\",{\"password\":\"%@\",\"username\":\"%@\",\"ip\":\"%@\",\"login_type\":\"IOS\",\"short_name\":null}]",self.mPassword.text,self.mUsername.text,[Settings getIPAddress]];

NSLog(@"login %@",body);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Settings getLoginUrl]]];
NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

But it sends an empty string to server. why so? I wish to send `base64` string as a request to server.

**UPDATE:**

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[\"Login\",{\"password\":\"%@\",\"username\":\"%@\",\"ip\":\"%@\",\"login_type\":\"IOS\",\"short_name\":null}]",self.mPassword.text,self.mUsername.text,[Settings getIPAddress]];



        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Settings getLoginUrl]]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[Settings getLoginUrl]);
       NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *base64EncodedStr = [postData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSData *base64EncodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64EncodedStr options:0];
        [request setHTTPBody:base64EncodedData];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[base64EncodedData length]];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *connectionError)
          {
              if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil)
              {
                  [self receivedLoginData:data];

              }
              else if ([data length] == 0 && connectionError == nil)
              {
                  [self emptyReply];
              }
              else if (connectionError != nil && connectionError.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut)
              {
                  [self timedOut];
              }
              else if (connectionError != nil)
              {
                  [self downloadError:connectionError];
              }
          }]resume];
```

Comment: do you mean send `data`, I see your post code.

Comment: yes... The post request has to be a base64 string.

Comment: In other words we call it as StringRequest when it comes to Android app dev

Answer (score 0):

NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength is a NSDataBase64EncodingOption and not a Base64Encoding.

You need to use for example [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encoding-on-the-iphone)

Comment: can you please explain it with reference to my code...thank you

Comment: You can do something like this:   `NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *base64EncodedStr = [postData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        NSData *base64EncodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64EncodedStr options:0];
        [request setHTTPBody:base64EncodedData];`

Comment: still its empty :(

Comment: That is strange - for string `["Login",{"password":"mPassword","username":"mUsername","ip":"[Settings getIPAddress]","login_type":"IOS","short_name":null}]` this code gives me `Request HTTPBody <5b224c6f 67696e22....`

Comment: same it give me the same but when it hits the server, it is empty