# iOS library to Encrypt AES128 CFB no padding

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

Does anyone know of an iOS library that allows us to encrypt using AES128 CFB mode with not padding. Looks like commoncrypto does not support this .

Thanks

Comment: I have made a code that can help to encrypt AES128 bit with CFB mode & no padding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997088/i-want-to-create-aes-128-using-cfb-encryption-with-no-padding-in-objective-c/37019462#37019462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest pushing OpenSSL into your project, if possible. A quick search for ["ios openssl"](http://www.google.com/search?q=ios%20openssl) returns a first hit for [Easy inclusion of OpenSSL into iOS projects](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-inclusion-of-openssl-into-iphone-app-projects/). See also [AES interoperability between .Net and iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538435/aes-interoperability-between-net-and-iphone)

Beware that without padding, you'll need to feed the cipher blocks of the correct size.