# AES encryption/decryption from Android to server

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I have one server and two clients. The server runs with Java and Jersey (Rest). 
One client is a Java client and the other is an Android client.

I want to send message encrypted with AES. So I have this code (on the server and clients) :

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

public String crypterMessage(String message) {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        String messageCrypte = new String(Hex.encodeHex(cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes())));
        mIv = cipher.getIV();
        return messageCrypte;
}

public String decrypterMessage(String messageCrypte) {
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(mIv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, obtenirCleSecrete(), ivParameterSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(messageCrypte.toCharArray())));
}
```

When I send encrypted message from the Java Client, the server decrypt it and crypt the response. The Java Client decrypt the response. It works perfectly.

But when the Android client send a encrypted message, the server can't decrypt it. I have a BadPaddingException : "Given final block not properly padded" on the server.

The server and the java client use SunJCE and the Android client uses AndroidOpenSSL as provider.

What's the problem with Android ?

PS : I use Hex.encode and Hex.decode from org.apache.commons. And I use Spring on Android.

**EDIT**

I found the problem but I don't know why. I have this code :

```
KeyGenerator generateurCle = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom securite = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        securite.setSeed(mCleCryptage.toByteArray());
        generateurCle.init(128, securite);
        mCleSecrete = generateurCle.generateKey();
```

The variable "mCleCryptage" is the same for the server and clients. But "mCleSecrete" differs between server and Android client. Server and Java Client have the same secret key.

I don't understand because all have the same class, the same code.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you're using the same key and IV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was securite.setSeed().
You can see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308957/encryption-using-aes-128-in-android-and-iphone-different-result) in the first post